# C++ - using return when the function being called on has parameters

Tags: c++, function, parameters, return

I have a function like this:

```
void functiont(int a, int b)
{
        if(playingnumber=="T")
        {
            returntransfer=1;
            struct A
            {
                ~A() // Destructor to run after returning variable
                {
                    void cardselecth(int playingcolorh, int playingnumberh);
                }
            }
            return returntransfer;
        }
}
```

Anyway I need to grab that returned variable without calling on int a or int b. So in another function I write

```
newvar=functiont(int a, int b);
```

And it gives a compile error. I don't know how else to do this. I could write functiont(a,b); and I get an error; I write functiont(int,int); and get an error. I've tried writing functiont(); but then it assumes the function's in the same file and I haven't defined it, which it isn't (I'm transferring across files here, so I need to define any parameters so it knows to refer to another file).

Comment: Your code simply doesn't make sense.  Why are you creating a struct in the middle of the function?  Also, you don't call functions like this: `newvar=functiont(int a, int b);`

Comment: You have a function declaration in the middle of the destructor's definition?

Comment: Code in this post literally makes no sense. Voting to close.

Comment: There should also be a compile error for missing semicolon after the struct definition

Comment: Looks like you need to read basic C++ books and learn simple examples, and not learn C++ by winging it.

Comment: @Musicrafter: I can give you C++ help in a chat, but this question is poorly asked

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to return an int, return type of your function should be int not void. I corrected the code as follows. Note the changes with comment

```
int functiont(int a, int b)
{
   int returntransfer=0; //change , declaration out of if block
                         // to maintain the scope of variable 
   if(playingnumber=="T")
        {
            returntransfer =1;

        }
        return returntransfer;//change
}
```

You can  declare a  struct variable inside a function, but it don't mean just by declaration it will be get called.

```
struct A
{
    ~A() // Destructor to run after returning variable
    {
       void cardselecth(int playingcolorh, int playingnumberh);
     }
};//change added ; at end of declaration.
```

**EDIT**
Adding complete program for answer to further questions:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int functiont(int a, int b)
{
   int returntransfer=0; //change , declaration out of if block
                         // to maintain the scope of variable 
   std::string playingnumber ="T"; //Added again for completness
   if(playingnumber=="T")
        {
            returntransfer =1;

        }

    struct A
{
    ~A() // Destructor to run after returning variable
    {
       void cardselecth(int playingcolorh, int playingnumberh);
     }
};//change added ; at end of declaration.
        return returntransfer;//change
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<functiont(2,3);
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the struct to have the semicolon. I changed the function to an int, but it still returns an error when I try to call this specific line from my code: transferred=cardselecth(int playingcolorh, int playingnumberh);

The specific errors it returns are as follows:
expected primary-expression before int
expected primary-expression before int
cardselecth was not declared in this scope

I know what the last error means, and I don't think I should be getting it. What kinds of characters could possibly come before the the two int values?

Comment: @Musicrafter I edited answer with complete compiled executed program

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do there, but at first this function is a void function so it can only return but not return a value. So your signature, respectively the void must be changed according to the type you want to return. 
In this case

```
int functiont(int a, int b)
```

would be appropriate.

When calling the function you have to pass it two arguments of type integer.

```
newvar = function(1, 2);
```

It's a good idea to post the error, too. Best regards